# I want to read text from Image in React native . (android & ios)

Tags: android, react-native, firebase-mlkit, google-mlkit

Currently I am using react-native-camera     "react-native-camera": "^4.2.1"
App Craches when I open camera.
But, If I remove this line Camera works fine.

> `onTextRecognized={(data) =>this.onTextRecognized(data)}`

Note: I have used react native ml kit for this purpose.
and I want to acheive text reading from image

```
    <RNCamera
      ref={ref => {
        this.camera = ref;
      }}
      style={styles.camera.preview}
      type={this.state.cameraType}
      flashMode={this.state.flashMode}
      ratio={this.props.ratio}
      captureAudio={false}
      autoFocus={this.props.autoFocus}
      whiteBalance={this.props.whiteBalance}
      androidCameraPermissionOptions={{
        title: 'Permission to use camera',
        message: 'We need your permission to use your camera',
        buttonPositive: 'Ok',
        buttonNegative: 'Cancel'
      }}
      androidRecordAudioPermissionOptions={{
        title: 'Permission to use audio',
        message: 'We need your permission to use your audio',
        buttonPositive: 'Ok',
        buttonNegative: 'Cancel'
      }}
      onTextRecognized={(data) => this.onTextRecognized(data)}
    />
```

Comment: react-native-camera is deprecated
https://github.com/react-native-camera/react-native-camera

Answer (score 0):

You can use `@react-native-firebase/mlkit`. It has a lot more functionality than just performing OCR. It also has both on-device support and cloud based support depending on your need.

Sample Code

```
import ml from '@react-native-firebase/ml';

const processingResult = await ml().cloudDocumentTextRecognizerProcessImage(media.uri);
```

method

```
const onImageSelect = async (media) => {
  if (!media.didCancel) {
    setImage(media.uri);
    const processingResult = await ml().cloudDocumentTextRecognizerProcessImage(media.uri);
    console.log(processingResult);
    setResult(processingResult);
  }
};
```

for full code read the below doc from below Link
https://www.section.io/engineering-education/react-native-firebase-text-recognition/

hope it's working